# Twilio REST API - Recordings: Date created is set when recording starts, or is stored?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Essentially wondering what the `DateCreated` field is, in a [Recording from Twilio's REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording). Is it set when a recording is finished, or set when the audio first starts being recorded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<DateCreated>` is set to the timestamp when the audio starts being recorded. To determine when a recording finished add `<Duration>` to it.

Comment: I figured as much, thanks. Here's to hoping they add this to the docs at some point.